# IPython in VScode can't link installed libraries

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

VScode jupyter notebook cannot open shared object files for a package that I've built locally when opened from outside the linux terminal:

```
ImportError: libismrmrd.so.1.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This error is not present when ipython is run in the terminal, nor when VScode is opened from the terminal (`$ code`) on the local machine, nor when jupyter notebook is opened in a browser (again, from the terminal).

Unfortunately when I do work remotely, I can't open VScode from the linux terminal (remote connection to my work machine from VScode on Windows 10)

I don't understand why this is happening.

I've checked the kernel and the jupyter notebook and ipython in the terminal. They're the same. The python paths (`sys.path`) are different, but both contain the path that I'm interested in. I've tried making the python paths identical, but I still get the same issue.

Ipython from terminal

```
In [3]: import platform
   ...: 
   ...: print( 'Version      :', platform.python_version())
   ...: print( 'Version tuple:', platform.python_version_tuple())
   ...: print( 'Compiler     :', platform.python_compiler())
   ...: print( 'Build        :', platform.python_build())
Version      : 3.10.6
Version tuple: ('3', '10', '6')
Compiler     : GCC 11.3.0
Build        : ('main', 'Mar 10 2023 10:55:28')
```

Output from jupyter notebook with VScode opened outside the linux terminal (or from my remote machine in VScode jupyter notebook)

```
Version      : 3.10.6
Version tuple: ('3', '10', '6')
Compiler     : GCC 11.3.0
Build        : ('main', 'Mar 10 2023 10:55:28')
```

There's some issue with linking shared libraries that I don't understand

Any help would be much appreciated

Sam

Comment: I think I've found the problem
```os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] ```

returns 
```KeyError: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'```

from the notebook inside VScode

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this:
Added a line to the `.env` file defined as my Python: Env File in VScode settings

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library
```

The import now works

Comment: What I still don't understand is why jupyter notebooks in VScode worked when opened from the terminal, but not from outside the terminal. The same `.env` file is defined in VScode settings either way.